# Hash string to a number % 16

Tags: algorithm, hash, redis, hex, modulo

I want to reuse or write a hashing algorithm that will hash a relatively short string to a  number 0 - 15. I want to use this to map a test to a specific Redis database (limited to 16 databases by default).

How would I go about to design such a hashing algorithm or seek out the right one that would optimize for low risk of collisions (since the target space is so small)?

Comment: There are lots of good string hash functions, like [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html#:~:text=If%20you%20just%20want%20to,K%26R%5B1%5D%2C%20etc.). You can just do modulus 16 on the result, as you suggest. If you have way more than 16 strings there's obviously bound to be lots of collisions - no way around that.

Comment: Suppose you have a relatively short, 10 chars string limited to only the 26 English alphabet lower case letters... You have 1.41E+14 possibilities, or around 2^47. Hashing this in a 2^4 target space will result, with the best possible algorithm, in 2^43 or about 8 trillions collisions for each value

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash function with high [uniformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity) and take the result modulo 16.

This should give you the lowest collision risk possible (the collision risk is still very high due to the tiny target space).